# Cant get Pyserial classes to work with uart

Tags: python, class, pyserial

I am trying to make an Uart Class in python which can receive data and send it. The meaning for my program is so that I can just use it as a driver and put it in the constructor and get the data I want, for example: `Uart = uart(arg1, arg2)` where `arg1` sends a number or a string for what kind of data I need, FX. Temperature or water level, and `arg2` is the data I receive.

```
import serial
import time


class uart():
    uart = serial.Serial('/dev/serial0', baudrate=9600)

    def __init__(self, write, read):
        self.read = read
        self.write = write

    def read(self, read):
        if uart.isopen():
            try:
                while True:
                    self.value = uart.readline()
                return self.value
            except:
                print("failed to recive data")

    def write(self, write):
        if uart.isopen():
            try:
                self.uart.write()
            finally:
                print("sent")
                time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myPh = uart("22",'')
```

Okay, i tried something more easy and i got the read def running, but the write wont work like i want i too..

```
import serial
import time


class uart(object):
    uart = serial.Serial('/dev/serial0', baudrate=9600)

    #   def __init__(self, write, read):
    #        self.read = read()
    #        self.write = write()

    def write(self):
        self.uart.write()
        print("sent")
        time.sleep(3)


    def read(self):
        while True:
            self.value = uart.readline()
            time.sleep(2)
            print(self.value)
            return self.value



if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        myTemp = uart()
        myTemp.write('hello')
        myTemp.read()
```

Comment: Your `.read()` and `.write()` methods might as well not exist, because you're overwriting them with the passed-in parameters in `.__init__()`.

Comment: so 'def read(self)' should be something else, like 'def readData()' or I am misunderstanding what you mean?

Comment: `read` is a perfectly good name for the method, you just need to *call* it rather than assign to it.

Comment: Okay so i tried something, that i think is what you mean, and i got my read up and running, but i cant get the write def working?